# How to auto commit and push on github?

Tags: git, github

I am using windows and i am completely new to github. I have installed desktop client. I wanted a single txt file to automatically uploaded to my github repository when it's changed or updated locally. I want this to completely automatic process as file is also getting updated automatically every hour and as soon as file gets updated i want it to be commit and pushed to my github repository.

Comment: https://github.com/gitwatch/gitwatch

Comment: Are you sure you need a VCS for this? Wouldn't something like Dropbox be a better fit?

Answer (score 8):

To auto commit every one hour you can create a batch file (`.bat`) with this content:

```
cd C:\path\to\your\git\project
git add --all
git commit -m "autoCommit %date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
git push
exit
```

Create a task on the Task Scheduler and run this file every one hour.

(You can also run it every 1 minute and you will be updated almost in "real time").

Comment: Can you please take a look at this one https://github.com/mvgrimes/git-autocommit i just found it and i think it is something like you have explained. I want it to keep running i don't want batch file to exit.

Comment: @xorro it looks like a nice tool but I didn't understand completely how to run it in Windows :/

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk very creative solution. I like it :)

Comment: I would write cd /d C:\path\to\your\git\project otherwise the bat file will stay in the original directory, not switching to the good one. Use the /d thing.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-commit won't work out of the box because every commit needs a commit message. Probably gitwatch, as proposed by Sid, will help you. I recommend you start by learning some Git basics, e.g. from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics.

Comment: @KingsleyChen I didn't down-vote, but it is more a comment than an answer. It just gives a direction how it probably could be solved, but does not provide a solution to the asked question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, every change you made need to commit depends on git basics as far i know. It's easy if u use a shortcuts and commit changes you made.

For example i work on visual studio :

`CTRL+F5`